# Rails JOIN returns seemingly correct SQL, but returns the wrong result

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join, inner-join

The setup I have has publications, drafts, and live versions. Publication has a polymorphic `belongs_to` since many different types of objects can be drafted.

```
# Publication.all
Publication id: 1, publishable_id: 2, publishable_type: "Foo", 
            original_id: 1, original_type: "Foo"

# published scope on Foo
select('*, MAX(publications.created_at)').
  joins(:publications).
  group('publications.original_id')

# Foo.published.all
[<Foo id: 1, ...>]
```

Here is the published scope's `to_sql`:

```
SELECT *, MAX(publications.created_at)
FROM "foos" 
INNER JOIN "publications" 
ON "publications"."publishable_id" = "foos"."id" 
AND "publications"."publishable_type" = 'Foo' 
GROUP BY publications.original_id
```

Because there is only one publication with a `publishable_id` of 2, I expect this query to return the second Foo. But when I call the published scope on Foo, I instead get the first one. How is this possible? I thought that an INNER JOIN would limit the results to where the join condition is satisfied? How am I getting the complete opposite of what I'm looking for?

Something interesting: just performing the joins returns the correct result:

```
self.class.unscoped.joins(:publications)
```

However, the published scope (shown above) returns the incorrect result. Is something happening with the SELECT or GROUP BY parts of the query that is causing this?

Comment: As there is only one publication, then why are you using `group by`? Although `group by` does not account on changing the number of query results but just changing the rows order. It is `select` that can affect the result.